# How do I make a Django ModelForm field with choices required if I include a default blank choice?

Tags: django, django-forms

My model looks like this:

```
class Shoe(models.Model):
    size = models.IntegerField(choices=sizeChoices)
    brand = models.ForeignKey('Brand', related_name='shoes', choices=brandChoices)
```

My ModelForm looks like this:

```
class ShoeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Shoe
        fields = ['brand', 'size']
```

I want the form to require an input other than the default blank choice, but I want to keep the blank value in the rendered set of options. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a [custom clean method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) to your `ShoeForm` and check for if the value is still blank. If so, raise a `ValidationError`.

```
class ShoeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Shoe
        fields = ['brand', 'size']

    def clean_brand(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['brand']
        if data == '':
            raise forms.ValidationError("You need to select one brand!")
        return data
```

In your `views.py` just check `if form.is_valid():` that's all.

Comment: You should use __init__ and set `required=True` on the brand field.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you really want to do is set required on the brand field:

```
class ShoeForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ShoeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['brand'].required = True
```